# How to properly use the django built-in login view

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm just getting started with Django, and I'm trying to use built-in features as much as possible.  As such, for user login, I'm using the built-in login view, and assigning it to the base url of my site:

```
urlpatterns=patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
    url(r'^/$','login',{'template':'mytemplate.html'}),
```

mytemplate.html looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    {%if form.errors %}
    <p> Invalid username/password combination, please try again </p>
    {% endif %}

    <h1>Welcome to My Site!</h1>
    <form action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.username.label_tag}}{{form.username}}
        {{form.password.label_tag}}{{form.password}}
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />        
    </form>
    <a href="password_reset/" id="forgot"> forgot username/password</a><br />
    <a href="register" id="new">new user</a>
</body>
</html>
```

my problem is, the template doesn't appear to be getting passed any of the context it's supposed to.  In the rendered HTML, all of my variable tags simply disappear (i.e. rather than being replaced by the appropriate values, thay are replaced with nothing).

I imagine I'm skipping some critical step, but I can't figure out what it is.  Any ideas?

Comment: Slightly off topic but you might want to check out django-registration

Answer (score 13):

You need to change from 'template' to 'template_name'

```
urlpatterns=patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
    url(r'^/$','login',{'template_name':'mytemplate.html'}),
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the template name from your url configuration. Django will then fall back to a standard template, that way you can see if you screwed up the template somehow or if something else is wrong.

My next guess would be to check your settings for the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. If you have defined any of them, be sure to include

```
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
```

If you haven't defined any, django will use a standard tuple, which allready includes the auth processor.

Comment: Acutally, the template name argument defaults to 'registration/login' which doesn't exist unless you create it, so you'll get a 404, not a standard template.

Comment: This did turn out to be helpful, though, because nothing changed.  It turned out my root url was "", not "/", so the pattern matching fell through to a previously created view which pointed to the same file.  I thought I'd already checked this, but I guess not, so thanks.

Since you gave the right advice for the wrong reason, I'll only upvote your answer for now.  If you revise the reason to something more helpful for posterity (i.e. future viewers of this question)  I'll accept it.  Thanks again.