# Django 1.7 & Zinnia (stable) - How can I make my blog private and invite-only?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, zinnia

I have been researching this for a couple days now and found a lot of possible solutions, however most tutorials or documentation pages are over a year old (except the official django stuff) and are intended for an older version of django..or they just don't explain things very clearly. I am relatively new to Django and also python so I kind of need a little more explanation that most tuts seem to be giving.

Basically what I am doing is making a private archive of files with a blog at the front of it. Non-members would only see a login page, and can only see the rest of the site if they register via invite code and log in.

I am currently using Zinnia as a simple blog app, and customizing its default template to fit my needs.

Does anyone know how I could go about implementing these features?

EDIT: I am going through the tutorial ['Handling Authentication & Authorization'](http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/authzn.html#authorization) as suggested, and everything seems to be going well until I must create class-based views. Since the tutorial is working with some sort of example 'contact list' type application and I am managing a zinnia blog, I was wondering if you could help me figure out the proper classes/models to use. My views.py file is currently as follows, which is probably incorrect:

```
#                           blog/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class LoggedInMixin(object):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoggedInMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class ListBlogView(LoggedInMixin, ListView):

    model = Entry
    template_name = 'base.html'

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Entry.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Not sure how I would alter this code to match what I am trying to do. I am pretty sure 'model', 'template_name', and the 'return' should correspond to something zinnia related but I am really stumped here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you could use a LoginRequiredMiddleware in order to check that user authenticated in every possible view. If not then redirect him to login page.

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1179/

Edit:

When it comes to authenticating users you should look these tutorials:

[How to properly use the django built-in login view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844503/how-to-properly-use-the-django-built-in-login-view)

[homepage login form Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208562/homepage-login-form-django)

http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/authzn.html

http://dustindavis.me/django-login-form-on-every-page/

It's going to take a while to finish them but you should practice a bit to get more confidence with Python and Django.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I know, I need a lot more practice. I am pretty proud of how far I have come in the past two weeks and I owe it all to just doing the tuts available online. For some reason I just couldn't find the right documentation or something, and of course, the learning curve on the docs tends to be a bit steep. Noob Question: Even though this login required middleware was posted in 2008, do you think it would conflict with my 1.7 django installation? I will mess with these tutorials and get back with the results.

Comment: I have made some changes to my main question, see edits :) I have made progress but have run into a bit of a snag.

Comment: You don't really need these views in your because zinnia has it's own views for displaying list of entries and entry detail. For beginning you should use function based views (Class Based Views are quite hard to learn at start).

Comment: I found an app called django-stronghold that gives me exactly what I need and a lot of control over which pages are/are not viewable to anonymous users. It automatically adds a mixin to all non-login pages etc..